# How can I launch Chrome from the terminal as an isolated instance with a blank profile?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to launch Chrome from the terminal as a separate process isolated from any currently running Chrome processes while also using a blank, guest or anonymous profile.

This is for benchmarking purposes as I would like to ensure there is no interference from extensions or profile settings from my existing Chrome profile.

Is there a launch flag that allows for this?

```bash
alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"

chrome --enable-precise-memory-info
```

Comment: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches « Peter Beverloo](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: `--disable-extensions` Disable extensions.